# how to deploy golang app with dependencies to the app engine with gcloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, deployment, gcloud

I have an app that uses "github.com/gorilla/mux" and I am able to deploy it with `goapp deploy`. But I cannot do the same with `gcloud preview app deploy` because I am facing this error:

```
Beginning deployment...
Copying files to Google Cloud Storage...
Synchronizing files to [<googlecloudsdk.api_lib.app.cloud_storage.BucketReference object at 0x10514e790>].
File upload done.
Updating module [api]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Deployment contains files that cannot be compiled: Compile failed:
2016/03/22 09:06:40 go-app-builder: build timing: 1×6g (42ms total), 0×6l (0 total)
2016/03/22 09:06:40 go-app-builder: failed running 6g: exit status 1

api.go:29: can't find import: "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
```

I want to be able to do it because I need to deploy from travisCI on merge and I want to use service-client.json for authorisation.

Is there any way around it?

Comment: Does [this](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=631) help?  Points to [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/hello-world#running_hello_world_on_app_engine), which is for Managed VMs, but looks like the same issue.

Comment: eadeploy will work only for Managed VM's which should have a bit different app structure (main func etc..)

Comment: Also had this issue but ended up just using `goapp deploy`

Comment: Same for me, I am using my oauth_refrash_token in CI for now. And there is a related issue here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-go/eoSSKKN_VmI

Comment: Did specify your [`$GOPATH`](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#GOPATH)?  Also, did you use [`go get`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Download_and_install_packages_and_dependencies) to import the required packages?  You can confirm using [`go list`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages) to see what packages have already been imported.

Comment: Yes, and "goapp serve" works as well

Comment: What is the directory structure of your app engine project and what is your `$GOPATH`?  Also, what version of the SDK are you using?  If your `$GOPATH` is set to the same as or within the project directory, you will likely get import errors.  Ideally, the `$GOPATH` should be **above** the project directory.  Also, if you are still attempting to use `gcloud preview app deploy`, I would suggest updating your Cloud SDK installation and using `gcloud app deploy` instead.

Comment: @user1835337 If you were able to solve this, you can post the answer here for other community members who may be seeing this same issue. If not, you can provide further information as Nicholas suggested to further troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

Since Google Cloud SDK 142.0.0 with app-engine-go 1.9.50, you should be able to deploy your application doing

```
gcloud beta app deploy
```

This also enables you to use CI/CD tools

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly, the way around this would be to use `goapp deploy` as is recommended by the App Engine documentation for the Go standard environment, [Deploying a Go App](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/uploadinganapp).  At the time when `gcloud preview app deploy` was available, goapp was recommended precisely for handling go's specific environment and dependency requirements.

Alternatively, if you're looking to use **gcloud**, you would need to use [`gcloud app deploy`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy) now.  `gcloud preview app deploy` has been [deprecated and/or removed as of June 29, 2016](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#11600_20160629).